# How would I properly add an array as a field when creating a new object that has arrays as a parameter?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

Example - I create a new class:

```
public class exampleClass

{

public int a;
public string b;

//array that holds three strings
public string[] c = new string[3]; 

//contructor
public exampleClass(int A, string B, string\[\] C){

    a=A;

    b=B;

    c=C;

 }
}
```

When I go to create a new object in the exampleClass class, I tried:

```
   public static List<exampleClass> exampleClassList = new List<exampleClass>();

exampleClassList.Add(new exampleClass(10, "bird", {"left", "right", "forward"}));
```

The 10 matches up properly with int a and the "bird" matches up properly with string b. How would I (if it is possible) implement the array string[] c as I create a new object? I tried simply adding the contents of the array in curly braces, but this is not correct.

Thank you for reading

Comment: `new string[] { "left", "right", "forward"}`

Comment: No need to initialize field `c`, `public string[] c;`is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
exampleClassList.Add(new exampleClass(10, "bird", new string[] {"left", "right", "forward"}));
```